# Historic origin of symbol $\mapsto$ to define a function

Tags: notation, math-history

Everything is in the title. We were wondering this evening with my girlfriend about the origin of the symbol $\mapsto$ (distinct from symbol $\to$) to define a function, and how students didn't know how to read it (where's the problem ? "f colon, x arrow f of x" ;()

Doesn't seem specific to France, so maybe not an invention of Bourbaki, but can't find anything on the history...

Any clue ?